# Interchage of summation and integral

Tags: calculus

I was doing a problem on calculus that is $\int_0^1\dfrac{\sin(\ln(x))}{\ln(x)} dx$
I tried to expand it using taylor series and integrated each term using gamma function
Then I realised what I did was switching integral and summation.So I don't know what I have done is correct or not . Is there any condition to switch summation and integral.And if there is a condition how to show $\dfrac{\sin(\ln(x))}{\ln x}$ satisfies it.

Comment: search up for uniform convergence

Comment: Thank u how will I prove that ts uniformly convergent

Answer (score 0):

Sum is a special case of integral. If you use Lebesgue integral, the sum is an integral with counting measure.

It can work even with Lebesgue measure, you can actually change each whole number $N$ to interval $[N,N+1)$ and then integal over $\Bbb{R}$ is the same as the sum over $\Bbb{Z}$. And if the sum involves only some of the whole numbers, just set the values for all other numbers to zero.

After you do this, you can change the order of integrals using the Fubini theorem. Fubini theorem says that the integrals may be swapped if the integrated function is integrable and the result of integration is smaller than infinity. So if the integral you have at the beginning exists and is finite, the double integral of the Taylor serie is the same so it also exists and is finite. The function you provided is bounded and measurable so the integral exists and therefore you can use Fubini theorem.

So yes, you can use that trick.

Comment: How is it related to uniform convergence

Comment: Sorry, I missed the second part of the question. I fixed it.

Comment: Thank u so much

Comment: Can u give an example where the switching of integral and summation fails.

Comment: It would fail if the integral didn't exist or would be infinite, for example $\int_0^1\frac1xdx$

Comment: Will all these come under measure theory

Comment: Where can I learn it

Comment: Can u recommend a good sours where I can study these I am just 16.

Comment: Yes, it comes all from the measure theory. I learnt that on the university. I know that from the lectures. These lectures were in Czech so I don't know how much you understand this language. I recommend you looking at some basics of measure theory, it looks nice.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107950/discussion-between-army1729-and-hume2).